# SKEmitterNode flashing randomly before showing normally

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have two particle emitters in my scene that for the most part work normally, but they are attached to another node that moves from off screen to on screen. The instant it enters the screen, there is a bright flash where the node enters the screen that is about 5-6 times the size of the emitter node, and then it looks normal. I thought maybe it was a result of advancing the simulation a couple seconds, but I made the alpha 0 before that and back to 1 after, and I still get the same weird flash.

Some code:

```
upperFlame = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"flames" ofType:@"sks"]];
lowerFlame = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"flames" ofType:@"sks"]];

upperFlame.alpha = 0;
lowerFlame.alpha = 0;
[upperFlame advanceSimulationTime:3];
[lowerFlame advanceSimulationTime:2];
upperFlame.alpha = 1;
lowerFlame.alpha = 1;

upperFlame.position = CGPointMake(8, -110);
lowerFlame.position = CGPointMake(7, 155);

[topBar addChild:upperFlame];
[bottomBar addChild:lowerFlame];
```

I tried like 60 times to get a screenshot of the flash, but it's too fast to get the timing right.

Comment: Is this on device ? simulator ? or both ?

Comment: Did you ever get to solve that problem? I currently have the exact same problem.